# Highcharts Datetime Issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm attempting to design a chart for displaying datetime based data:

https://jsfiddle.net/kyledecot/LLExL/5539/

This works however Highcharts doesn't seem to like the format of my `x` axis data. What format should I be using for this?

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
       type: 'datetime'
    },    
    series: data
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your date value are strings here and are not in expected javascript time. See docs [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes). You should either convert your timestamps to javascript time (integer) or use something like this in your data series:

```
data: [
[Date.UTC(year,month,day,hours,minutes,seconds,millisec), yValue]
]
```